# sed: using a variable for command and address

Tags: bash, sed

While trying to write a bashscript on Ubuntu I came across the following issue:

```
iconname="'application:\/\/nautilus.desktop'"
echo "iconname: $iconname"
sedvariable=\"s/$iconname[,]*//\"
echo "sedvariable: $sedvariable"
settings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites | sed ${sedvariable}
```

I always get an error saying "unknown command"

```
sed: -e Ausdruck #1, Zeichen 1: Unbekannter Befehl: `"'
```

However, the variable "sedvariable" looks fine like this:

```
sedvariable: "s/'application:\/\/nautilus.desktop'[,]*//"
```

When entering the command manually it works just fine

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites | sed "s/'application:\/\/nautilus.desktop'[,]*//"
```

Why does sed not accept the command from my variable? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: sed won't allow the whole command to be compressed in a single variable.

Comment: sed won't allow
    settings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites | sed "s/$iconname[,]*//"
neighter

Comment: I don't see where you are using `sedvariable`. Neither `sedvariable` nor `iconname` appear in your `gsettings` command line.

Comment: Hey Kaz, sorry by copying the lines to the post I mixed something up. It's now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
          sedvariable="-e s/$iconname[.]*//"
          gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites | sed "$sedvariable"
```

Comment: thank you very much! This works perfectly! Why is it that sed can't use my variable as it was? Is there any obvious reason I am missing or is it just a sed-specific thing?

Comment: @user3780567 As I see it, double quotes around `sed` expression are to be interpreted by bash (they mean, roughly: “don't split this string on spaces”). With `sedvariable=\"s/$iconname[,]*//\"`, you escape double quotes, making them *part of* the string contained in your variable. When executing `sed ${sedvariable}`, your shell parses quotes, then perform variables substitution, and remaining quotes are given to `sed`. As if you wrote `sed '"s/$iconname[,]*//"'`.